# C# ORM - Multiple table fields to single property

Tags: c#, database, orm

I have a table of addresses (see Figure 1) that has 5 fields dedicated to storing 'address lines'. In my Address object I wanted to store these fields in an array (see Figure 2). How would I go about mapping my object to the database in this scenario? I have a limited understanding and small amount of experience with EntityFramework and nHibernate so please could any complex practices be explained fully

Also, I know it's not a great example but was the most convenient one I could think of

Figure 1
[image: Address Database]

Figure 2
[image: Class Diagram]

Thank you

Comment: Why use an array? Keep it simple, add a string property for each address line.

Comment: So the address lines was more an example to add context to the question rather than this is a specific problem I am facing. What you have suggested is the obvious solution but I was hoping to get an answer that I could then apply to other scenarios